# Difference between binding object/properties in ListView and ListBox

Tags: c#, linq, listview, listbox, datatemplate

I have a ListView which shows list of employees and per each SelectionChanged event it shows different information about each employee in a set of textboxes.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" x:Name="lvEmployeeList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="385" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="1,1,1,1" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvEmployeeList, Path=SelectedItem.EmployeeID}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Which works fine. Then I thought to learn about DataTemplate so this time I used a ListBox and it shows the information again in the Listbox (just a simple version where it shows few fields in each row of the listbox) the problem is that when SelectionChanged happens I get an runtime error as

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lstEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeID}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackgroundID}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeName}" />
                </StackPanel>                        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.EmployeeID}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
```

Basically in the ViewModel I have a linq statement as:

```
PropertyEmployee = Employees.FirstOrDefault(item => item.EmployeeID == param.ToString());
```

Can you tell me what is causing this error? in ListView it is fine but in ListBox I'm getting null object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue by addeing a selected property in my viewModel

```
public Employee SelectedEmployee { get; set; }
```

Then binding the SelectedItem to that property in a `OneWayToSource` mode

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEmployee, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

Make `ProcessCommand` take no parameters

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessCommand}"/>
```

and finally, inside `ProcessCommand` execution, retreive your `Employee` id and do whatever from there ...

```
var id = SelectedEmployee.EmployeeId;

// Do whatever you want
```

Hope this helps